# passing Access.Application object to a function: Dim, Set, Object how to make it work?

Tags: ms-access, vba, pass-by-reference, currying

I came upon this (modified) function in a Stack Overflow page and have been trying to get it to work without giving up on the passed object (if I handle the `Access.Application` strictly within the first routine it will work).

Yes I know of a number of ways to get the same answer (mostly from other posts on the stack), **but there is a general concept here of passing objects to functions that I would like to master**--please forget for a moment that the function checks the existence of a table.

```vb
Function FCN_CheckTblsExist(theDatabase As Access.Application, _
tableName As String) As Boolean  

'access.Application.CurrentData.AllTables.Count
'etc is the 'workaround enabling disposal of 
'the "theDatabase" object variable

    ' Presume that table does not exist.
    FCN_CheckTblsExist = False

    ' Define iterator to query the object model.
    Dim iTable As Integer

    ' Loop through object catalogue and compare with search term.


    For iTable = 0 To theDatabase.CurrentData.AllTables.Count - 1
        If theDatabase.CurrentData.AllTables(iTable).Name = tableName Then
            FCN_CheckTblsExist = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next iTable


End Function


Function callFCN_CheckTblsExist(tableName As String)  
'this is an example of a curried function?--step down in dimensionality

Dim bo0 As String    
Dim A As Object
Set A = CreateObject("Access.Application")

bo0 = FCN_CheckTblsExist(A, tableName)

MsgBox tableName & " Exists is " & bo0

End Function
```

I don't know if the (`theDatabase As Access.Application,` . ) part is correct, that may be the root of the problem, rather than the Dim, Set, Object (New?) gymnastics that may be required in the auxiliary procedure. Maybe there is a reference library problem (I'm running Access 2013).

**Update:** I am not sure the following is robust enough but this is what I meant earlier in the post, which is just being put here for completeness.  BTW, this is not a split application so maybe that is why the following works.  I appreciate HansUp's post, Not enough can be said on this subject.  Anyway

```vb
Public Function FCN_CheckTblsExist(tableName As String) As Boolean   'Call this function once for every table

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Dim appAccess As New Access.Application
Dim theDatabase As Access.Application

    ' Presume that table does not exist.
    FCN_CheckTblsExist = False

    ' Define iterator to query the object model.
    Dim iTable As Integer

    For iTable = 0 To Access.Application.CurrentData.AllTables.Count - 1
        If Access.Application.CurrentData.AllTables(iTable).Name = tableName Then
            FCN_CheckTblsExist = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next iTable

End Function
```

Just wanted to add that this last function I posted technically would be considered to be partial or no currying depending on how much the scope of the function was limited by invoking "Access.Application.CurrentData.AllTables." as a substitute for "theDatabase", only substituting the specific string created by Access.Application.CurrentDb.Name into the original function ...(theDatabse,... would it be a true full currying.

Anyway passing objects to functions and the libraries and their methods are the primary focus of this discussion.  When I get the DAO issue worked i should have a better feel for what may be going on and then I'll post and mark the best solution accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not really about passing an `Access.Application` object to your other function.  Instead you create the `Access.Application` and later check for the existence of a table without having opened a database within that Access session.  In that situation, `theDatabase.CurrentData.AllTables.Count` should trigger error 
2467, *"The expression you entered refers to an object that is closed or doesn't exist."*

I revised both procedures and tested them in Access 2010.  Both compile and run without errors and produce the result I think you want.

```vb
Function FCN_CheckTblsExist(theDatabase As Access.Application, _
        tableName As String) As Boolean

    Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
    Dim blnReturn As Boolean

    blnReturn = False
    For Each tdf In theDatabase.CurrentDb.TableDefs
        If tdf.Name = tableName Then
            blnReturn = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next ' tdf
    FCN_CheckTblsExist = blnReturn
End Function

Function callFCN_CheckTblsExist(DbPath As String, tableName As String)
    Dim bo0 As Boolean
    Dim A As Object

    Set A = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    A.OpenCurrentDatabase DbPath
    bo0 = FCN_CheckTblsExist(A, tableName)
    MsgBox tableName & " Exists is " & bo0
    Debug.Print tableName & " Exists is " & bo0
    A.Quit
    Set A = Nothing
End Function
```

Note I didn't include any provision to check whether the *DbPath* database exists before attempting to open it.  So you will get an error if you give it a path for a database which does not exist.

**DAO Reference Issues**:

*DAO 3.6* was the last of the older DAO series.  It only supports the older MDB type databases.  When Access 2007 introduced the ACCDB database type, a new DAO library (*Access database engine Object Library*, sometimes referred to as *ACEDAO*) was introduced.  In addition to supporting ACCDB databases, *ACEDAO* can also support the older MDB types.

When setting references, don't attempt to choose both.

Here is a screenshot of my project references:

[image: VBE Project References]

When I examine my project references in the Immediate window, notice that *ACEDAO* is even referred to as just *DAO*.  I also ran the *callFCN_CheckTblsExist* procedure to demonstrate it works without a *DAO 3.6* reference:

[image]

That was all based on Access 2010.  You're using Access 2013, so your *ACEDAO* version number may be different, but everything else should be the same.

Comment: I am getting a run time error on line = "For Each tdf In theDatabase.CurrentDb.TableDefs", I tried to load DAO 3.6

Comment: Getting a run time error on line = "For Each tdf In theDatabase.CurrentDb.TableDefs", I tried to load DAO 3.6 object library, that may be my problem, I have the following references available: vba, ms access 15.9 object L, OLE Autom, MS Office 15.0 Access DB engine, Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 L.  I tried it with a full string for the databases path and name, also with access.application.CurrentDb.Name in lieu of the the string--no success.  I am afraid that maybe there is bad conflict with the reference library-say this because usually I get a warning but the reference is still allowed

Comment: Remove the DAO 3.6 object library reference.  The Access database engine object library provides DAO features.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of solutions along with a much simpler way to check if a table exists:

**Workspace/Database; (much faster than using Application)**

```
Function TestFunction_DataBase()
  Dim ws As Workspace
  Dim db As Database

  Set ws = CreateWorkspace("", "admin", "", "dbUseJet")
  Set db = ws.OpenDatabase("the db path", , , CurrentProject.Connection)

  MsgBox TdefExists_DataBase(db, "the table name")

  db.Close
  ws.Close
  Set db = Nothing
  Set ws = Nothing

End Function

Function TdefExists_DataBase(ac As Database, strTableName As String) As Boolean
  'check to see if table exists
  On Error GoTo ErrHandler
  Dim strBS As String

  strBS = ac.TableDefs(strTableName).Name
  TdefExists_DataBase = True
  Exit Function
ErrHandler:
  TdefExists_DataBase = False
End Function
```

**Application:**

```
Function TestFunction_Application()
  Dim ac As New Access.Application

  ac.OpenCurrentDatabase "the db path"

  MsgBox TdefExists_Application(ac, "the table name")

  ac.Quit
  Set ac = Nothing

End Function

Function TdefExists_Application(ac As Access.Application, strTableName As String) As Boolean
  'check to see if table exists
  On Error GoTo ErrHandler
  Dim strBS As String

  strBS = ac.CurrentDb.TableDefs(strTableName).Name
  TdefExists_Application = True
  Exit Function
ErrHandler:
  TdefExists_Application = False
End Function
```

**Within the Current Database:**

```
Function TdefExists(strName As String) As Boolean
    'check to see if query exists
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Dim strBS As String
    strBS = CurrentDb.TableDefs(strName).Name
    TdefExists = True
    Exit Function
  ErrHandler:
    TdefExists = False
End Function
```